# In Acrobat, is there a way to limit page turns to clicking hyperlinks only in Full Screen View?

Tags: acrobat

I want users to click hyperlinks to advance to next page so I need to disable all other methods for users to advance pages. (I'm creating an interactive prototype, so the branching logic will not work if users can advance pages by simply clicking anywhere on the page).

The closest thing that I can find is Edit/Preferences/Full Screen and unclicking "Left click to go forward one page", however this only works inside of Acrobat and does not work after I save the file and open it in Acrobat Reader. I'm trying to use Full Screen because the timing for slide transitions work in Full Screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the click to advance property using JavaScript.

Not tested, but

```
app.fs.clickAdvances = false ;
```

in a document-level script, or in the pageOpen script of the page at which the document opens, should already do it.

And if it really should prevent any navigation except via links, you'd split up your document in single pages and open/close those single-page documents.